# Offering users pro features vs normal users

Tags: java, android, security

For about 2 years I've been developing a business card reader application and I've published 2 versions of it on the Google Play Store (one paid and another free).

Recently I've decided to offer cloud storage for those business cards. I've created my PHP backend and it's almost contested, but I am facing one major issue.

I would like to offer the free users a chance to test my service and offer them a limited number of cloud cards, while the pro users would have unlimited number of cards to store.

I don't know what would be the best approach to accomplish this in order to offer my existing pro users this functionality while limiting them to only one account/app paid.

I was thinking about in-app purchases, but I don't see how I could unlock the purchase for the users who already both the app.

I am open to any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

In your MySQL database, add a column for cloud services expiry date. Now in PHP if your user chose try, store the date a month from now, and if they chose purchase, enter the date their purchase expires. Finally, before a user uses the service, check if the date has expired to determine whether to let them use the cloud service.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I'll got with Google's in-app billing

Comment: Its a good choice but i never heard about trial using inapp purchase